# keys file is opened by another wallet program

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

First of all restoring my wallet is not an issue, no inocent XMR's are being harmed here.

My issue my pc crashed with my wallet open I am using monero-gui latest version on Ubuntu.

While starting the monero-gui after a reboot the monero-wallet-gui does not want to open the wallet anymore

```
ERROR   frontend    src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:416   Error opening wallet with password:  internal error: "/path/to/monero-storage/redacted/redacted.keys" is opened by another wallet program
```

Being curious to which program/user was having this keys file open I tried to do some research.

But `fuser` came up empty

```
fuser /path/to/monero-storage/redacted/redacted.keys
```

`lsof` at least found some traces monero-wallet-gui but the specific keys file was not opened

```
lsof | grep monero
```

I killed the process anyways but still the same error when trying to restart the wallet.(later I realized this where just leftovers from me starting the wallet gui before)

Then I moved on lookup for some hidden lock files but `ls -la` did not reveal anything in the monero-storage folder this revealed nothing.

So I gave up searching my self as this is all the linux knowledge I have to investigate.

But still curious to why this is happening I was wondering if someone where knows this error and what causes it?

Comment: `sudo lslocks` shows which commands locked which files and `sudo flock -u <file>` can remove a file lock.

Comment: @jtgrassie thanks for you replay. It help motivate me search further in the end i found that it was as simple as file ownership. I started the monero-wallet-gui from the command line using sudo so the keys file was owned by root

Comment: Please add an answer with your solution.

Comment: @jtgrassie - thanks for that command (lslocks) - turned out I had a zombie wallet process. I did a kill -HUP <pid> and everything worked again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end it turned out the the keys file owner was root setting this to the correct owner with chown solved the problem.

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER keys /pathto/monero-gui/monero-storage/$USER/$USER.keys
sudo chown $USER:$USER keys /pathto/monero-gui/monero-storage/$USER/$USER
```

It was caused by me using sudo the first time I run the wallet this created the wallets keys file with root as owner.